# Packages Crashing R after Using OpenBLAS

Tags: r, openblas

So I have two R's installed (both v 3.5.0), one running on the default BLAS (for Mac) and one running on OpenBLAS. They are not installed on the same location on my Mac. I'm going to call the one with default BLAS (normal R), the other is Open R. Normal R runs perfectly. The one for OpenBLAS has issues. Specifically Open R is struggling with packages. I can tell Open R where to find the already installed packages Normal R but when I try to load a package this message is returned:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

followed by a traceback.    Alternatively, if I try to install a package from CRAN I get the same warning. I really need OpenBLAS to work with R (I'm doing benchmark research) but am stuck on what I need to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think many Mac users try using OpenBlas. https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS#supported-os indicates that it is "experimental". See https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Which-BLAS-is-used-and-how-can-it-be-changed_003f for instructions on using vecLib instead.

Comment: The default BLAS on Mac is the Accelerate framework. It is linked against using the following linker flag: `-framework Accelerate`. It by far outperforms any BLAS implementation including MKL in mixed operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install R via homebrew with the OpenBLAS option.

```
brew install r --openblas
```

Comment: I know it's frustrating, but on Stack Overflow we don't allow posting comments as answers. When you get enough reputation, you will be able to comment on all posts. Until then, please answer questions that don't require additional clarification from the asker.